# 404 status code in phpunit

Tags: api, rest, symfony

I'm trying to functional test the HTTP status code and all my request return 404. I'm using symfony2 and api rest, and here's the code:

```
class UserControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

public function testdeleteAction()
{
    $client = $this->createClient();
    // $client   = static::createClient();
    $crawler  = $client->request('DELETE','/user',array(),array(),array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'),array());
    $response = $client->getResponse();
    // print_r($response);
    // exit();
    // $this->assertTrue($response->isSuccessful());
    $this->assertSame(Response::HTTP_CREATED, $response->getStatusCode());

}
public function testpeopleAroundAction()
{
    $tab = array(
        "images" => array(
            "smallImage"=>array(
                    "w"=>"130",
                    "h"=>"100",
                    "density"=>"2"
                ),
            "bigImages"=>array(
                    "w"=>"1400",
                    "h"=>"700",
                    "density"=>"2"
                )
            )
        );
    $tab = json_encode($tab);
    $client   = static::createClient();
    $crawler  = $client->request('POST', '/users/around',array(),array(),array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'),$tab);
    $response = $client->getResponse();
    $this->assertSame(Response::HTTP_CREATED, $response->getStatusCode());
}
}
```

here is code of my routing in my bundle :

```
bla_api_delete_account:
pattern:  /user.{_format}
defaults: { _controller: BLAApiBundle:User:delete, _format: ~ }
requirements:
    _method: DELETE
bla_api_get_users_around:
pattern:  /users/around.{_format}
defaults: { _controller: BLAApiBundle:User:peopleAround, _format: ~ }
requirements:
    _method: Post
```

when I run the command

```
phpunit -c app
```

i get :

```
1) BLA\ApiBundle\Tests\Controller\UserControllerTest::testdeleteAction
Failed asserting that 404 is identical to 201.

2) BLA\ApiBundle\Tests\Controller\UserControllerTest::testpeopleAroundAction
Failed asserting that 404 is identical to 201.
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must be use slash in the end of routes.

Use:

```
$crawler = $client->request('DELETE','/user/',array(),array(),array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'),array());
```

Instead of

```
$crawler = $client->request('DELETE','/user',array(),array(),array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'),array());
```

By the way, it is a good practice invoke the router component on setup and then load the route. For instance:

```
class UserControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    protected $router;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->router = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('router');
    }

    public function testdelete()
    {
        $crawler = $client->request('DELETE', $this->router->generate('bla_api_delete_account', array('format' => 'json')));

    }

 }
```